# How to get the Value of an Attribute with DomNode at startup

Tags: php, xpath, attributes, dom-node

i`d like to get a value of a specific attribute directly without using foreach e.g.

**my code:**

```
    $xmldoc = new DOMDocument;
    $xmldoc->loadXML($this->Stream);

    $xpa = new DOMXPath($xmldoc);
    $titles = $xpa->query("//tpd:ParameterSet[@ProcessUsage='Customer']/tpd:Parameter/tpd:CustomerInfo");

    foreach ($titles as $title) {

        if ($title->hasAttributes()) {
            foreach ($title->attributes as $attribute) {
                print "AttributName= " . $attribute->name . "\n";
                print "AttributValue= " . $attribute->value . "\n";
            }
        }
```

**so far it will gives you the output:**

```
"T:\Program\PHP\php.exe" T:\run.php
AttributName= CustomerID
AttributValue= 1223
AttributName= CustomerOrderID
AttributValue= 1552045326210

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**my question:**
Is it possible to grab the AttributValue of tpd:CustomerInfo/CustomerOrderID directly?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The XPath to get the attribute directly would be: `//tpd:ParameterSet[@ProcessUsage='Customer']/tpd:Parameter/tpd:CustomerInfo/@CustomerOrderID`

Comment: okay, and how can i output this value in php?